# How can I append div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have this div

```
        <div class="row deliver-to forms">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Region</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="region-to" id="region-to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>District</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="district-to" id="district-to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Town</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="town-to" id="town-to">
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-flat mt-3 offset-10 add_place" type="button" id="add_place">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

How can I actually append this entire div after itself by clicking on this button?

Entire structure of my code looks like:

```
        <div class="row deliver-to forms">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Region</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="region-to" id="region-to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>District</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="district-to" id="district-to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Town</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="town-to" id="town-to">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-flat mt-3 offset-10 add_place" type="button"
                id="add_place">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
```

Comment: put your div inside a container and give that container an id then make a listener on you button onClick on that button use jquery selector for your container div and use append function to append the new div on that container

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? There should be plenty of resources on SO on how to add elements to the DOM.

Comment: @Andreas i have tried ```$('#add_place').on('click', function() {
            let self = $("#form");
            self.append(self);
        });``` but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: First, this should be part of your question ;)  Second, this only "moves" the element with id `form`. If you want a copy of it you have to `.clone()` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function(){
        $(".next").append("<div class=\"row deliver-to forms\">\n" +
            "            <div class=\"col-4\">\n" +
            "                <label>Region</label>\n" +
            "                <input class=\"w-50 mt-2 form-control\" type=\"text\" data-id=\"region-to\" id=\"region-to\">\n" +
            "            </div>\n" +
            "            <div class=\"col-4\">\n" +
            "                <label>District</label>\n" +
            "                <input class=\"w-50 mt-2 form-control\" type=\"text\" data-id=\"district-to\" id=\"district-to\">\n" +
            "            </div>\n" +
            "            <div class=\"col-4\">\n" +
            "                <label>Town</label>\n" +
            "                <input class=\"w-50 mt-2 form-control\" type=\"text\" data-id=\"town-to\" id=\"town-to\">\n" +
            "            </div>\n" +
            "        </div>")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row deliver-to forms">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Region</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="region-to" id="region-to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>District</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="district-to" id="district-to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Town</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="town-to" id="town-to">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-flat mt-3 offset-10 add_place" type="button"
                id="add_place">
            <i class="fa fa-plus">click</i>
        </button>
        <div class="next"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : try to wrap this with a div of specific id.

```
<div id="newrow">
    <div class="row deliver-to forms">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Region</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="region-to" id="region-to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>District</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="district-to" id="district-to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Town</label>
                <input class="w-50 mt-2 form-control" type="text" data-id="town-to" id="town-to">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Step 2 : Create a variable in jquery and assign the element what you want to append.
Example:

```
var element = "<div> New Div Appending</div>"
```

Step3: Jquery to append to wrapped div.

```
$("#newrow").append(element)
```

Comment: if you want to append as soon as the container, use "prepend".